# No display signal from graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, display, motherboard, pci-express, xeon

I am trying to figure out whether the graphics card is dead or just incompatible with the rest of my hardware. I've got:

- Motherboard: [Intel S1200KPR](https://ark.intel.com/products/67346/Intel-Server-Board-S1200KPR)
- CPU: [Intel Xeon E3-1270 v2](https://ark.intel.com/products/65727/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1270-v2-8M-Cache-3_50-GHz)
- Graphics card: [SAPPHIRE HD 7770](http://www.sapphiretech.com/productdetial.asp?pid=E526513F-4894-495A-8859-972F2F488D42&lang=eng)

The card has DVI, HDMI and DisplayPort connectors. I tried all of them. The monitor detects that the cable is connected ('cause when you plug it out, it says no cable) but says there is no signal. The fan on the card is spinning fine.

To prove that the rest of the hardware is OK, I plugged another graphics card (ATI-102-A924B Radeon X1300), connected it via composite video cable and saw it all working.

Does that mean my SAPPHIRE HD 7770 is dead? Or is it just somehow incompatible with the motherboard or CPU?

Comment: Has it ever worked?  Your GPU isn't incompatible with your CPU

Comment: @Ramhound I bought it second hand so no idea!

Comment: I meant the GPU with your computer.  Doesn't matter, it should work, if it doesn't then it's a hardware problem.  You have ruled out pretty much everything other than the GPU itself by your test